# How can I launch OCUnit test on iPhone from Command line

Tags: iphone, command-line, ocunit, octest

I want to run unit test on iPhone without using Xcode. Is there any command line utility to run OCunit test on iPhone device. 
I also tried fruit-strap but it only launches App not OCtests. "fruitstrap -d path_of_app" this command install app but I did not found any way to install and run octest on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the similar issue, I've opened recently: [Is there any non-Xcode-based command line testing tool for Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714356/is-there-any-non-xcode-based-command-line-unit-testing-tool-for-objective-c).

There is the answer by @MalteTancred. I am trying to adapt his answer to my project and can say that it is not a very easy task to get the stuff (that Xcode does out of box) to work when made by hands in command line.

Comment: I've just updated my answer there with description how Travis uses awk to capture octest's exit code from its output. It is needed to know if a test suite has passed or failed.