# Is there any non-Xcode-based command line unit testing tool for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

The post [Compiling Objective-C without GUI](http://codeseekah.com/2012/09/12/compiling-objective-c-without-a-gui/) says the following:

*To compile Objective-C on OSX the easy way you have to get XCode, which is free to obtain from the Application Store. Getting XCode will ensure you obtain the necessary frameworks (headers), like Foundation, Cocoa, etc. This will, however, not provide you with the necessary command line tools to compile Object-C from the command line. Open up XCode, go to Preference > Downloads > Components and Install Command Line Tools. This will install gcc, clang, make, etc.*

I am looking for a non-Xcode-based tool to address this my question, I've just opened: [Is it possible to make an Objective-C project to be tested on Travis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713241/is-it-possible-to-make-an-objective-c-project-no-ui-no-simulator-to-be-tested)

This tool should meet the following requirements:

- It should be not related to Xcode in any way.
- The following level of simplicity is pretty enough: just some `int main {}` code collecting all test-cases files nearby and running test assertions on the code I want to test (like `ST-` in SetTestingKit or `GH-` in GHUnit)
- I don't need UI, GUI, Xcode, simulator.
- It **will be great** if it could work both on Mac and Ubuntu (yeah, Travis), possibly using
  [GNUstep](https://github.com/gnustep) like the quoted post describes.

**UPDATE BASED ON ACCEPTED ANSWER:**

The following simple setup, based on what Malte Tancred have said in the accepted answer, seems pretty enough for my current needs:

Three files, all in the tests directory of my project:

**octest.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        SenSelfTestMain();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC=clang # or gcc

# Trick to get current dir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322936/common-gnu-makefile-directory-path
TESTS_DIR:= $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
PROJECT_DIR:= $(TESTS_DIR)/..

FRAMEWORKS_PATH:= -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
FRAMEWORKS:= -framework Foundation -framework SenTestingKit
LIBRARIES:= -lobjc
INCLUDE_PATHS:= -I$(PROJECT_DIR)/Projectfiles\
                -I$(TESTS_DIR)/TestHelpers

SOURCE_FILES = $(wildcard $(PROJECT_DIR)/Projectfiles/*.m)

SOURCE_TEST_SUITE = $(wildcard $(TESTS_DIR)/Tests/*.m)

SOURCE_TESTS = $(TESTS_DIR)/TestHelpers/TestHelpers.m\
                 octest.m


CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -fobjc-arc -g -v $(SOURCE_FILES) $(SOURCE_TEST_SUITE) $(SOURCE_TESTS)
LDFLAGS=$(LIBRARIES) $(FRAMEWORKS)
OUT=-o octest

all:
    $(CC) $(FRAMEWORKS_PATH) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OUT)
```

**runtests**

```
#!/bin/bash
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
make
./octest
```

**UPDATE TO CAPTURE EXIT CODE:**

A few days after I had asked this question, Travis announced Objective-C support:

http://about.travis-ci.org/blog/introducing-mac-ios-rubymotion-testing/

Though there are default scripts they suggest to use to make builds, I have decided to take the approach described here and still use octest instead of approach with xcodebuild that Travis uses.

By default travis setup relies on the build scripts written by Justin Spahr-Summers: https://github.com/jspahrsummers/objc-build-scripts:

They use **awk** to capture exit code from xcodebuild's output, since it always exists with 0 exit code, even if the whole test suite has failing!

OCTest behaves the same way - it always exists with 0 code, and here is how I've used simplified version of Travis **awk** script for my needs of building it the way I decribed above:

**octest.awk**

```
# Exit statuses:
#
# 0 - No errors found.
# 1 - Build or test failure. Errors will be logged automatically.

BEGIN {
    status = 0;
}

{
    print;
    fflush(stdout);
}

/[0-9]+: (error|warning):/ {
    errors = errors $0 "\n";
}

/with [1-9]+ failures?/ {
    status = 1;
}

END {
    if (length(errors) > 0) {
        print "\n*** All errors:\n" errors;
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    exit status;
}
```

**runtests**

```
#!/bin/bash

export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks

make

runtests ()
{
  ./octest 2>&1 | awk -f "octest.awk"

  local awkstatus=$?

  if [ "$awkstatus" -eq "1" ]
  then
    echo "Test suite failed"
    return $awkstatus
  else
    echo "Test suite passed"
    return 0
  fi
}

echo "*** Building..."

runtests || exit $?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your main question is yes:
there are command line testing tools for Objective-C
that does not depend on Xcode.

For example,
you can use OCUnit/SenTestingKit without using Xcode.
All you have to do
is to point your compiler/linker to the framework.
Consider the follwing file, `octest.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

int main() {
  @autoreleasepool {
    SenSelfTestMain();
  }
  return 0;
}

@interface MyTest : SenTestCase
@end

@implementation MyTest
- (void)testSomething {
  STAssertEquals(1, 2, @"fail");
}
@end
```

Compile it:

```
clang -o octest octest.m -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -framework Foundation -framework SenTestingKit
```

Now run it

```
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks ./octest
```

and you should see something like

```
Test Suite '/tmp/octest(Tests)' started at 2013-04-04 12:34:49 +0000
Test Suite 'MyTest' started at 2013-04-04 12:34:49 +0000
Test Case '-[MyTest testSomething]' started.
octest.m:16: error: -[MyTest testSomething] : '1' should be equal to '2': fail
Test Case '-[MyTest testSomething]' failed (0.000 seconds).
Test Suite 'MyTest' finished at 2013-04-04 12:34:49 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
Test Suite '/tmp/octest(Tests)' finished at 2013-04-04 12:34:49 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.001) seconds
make: *** [default] Error 1
```

This example does depend on Xcode
in that it uses the bundled SenTestingKit framework
but the general process of building and running the tests
as described above
does not depend on Xcode.

Now,
to get this running on a linux system
you'd have to install SenTestingKit (and most probably GNUstep),
but with those components in place
the build and test process should be essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't know about 'SenSelfTestMain()'. Could you please extend your answer with telling me how I could, using your example, "collect all test-cases .m-files nearby like Xcode does in a test target" (for example: what if MyTest is in a separate MyTest.m file, not in the same octest.m file?). Sorry, if I am asking something dead simple - I am the guy who is learning C/Objective-C in an "up to down" way, from Xcode level to the grounds.

Comment: Ah, the most simple approach is to add #import "MyTest.m" above the main() function, correct? I've just got it working this way.

Comment: You don't have to `#import` any header files when using automatic test discovery. Just make sure you link the test cases into your executable, or load them dynamically at runtime and `SenSelfTestMain()` will find the tests. This is what happens in Xcode; it runs the `otest` executable which in turn loads the test bundle containing the test cases.

Comment: What a useful piece of knowledge! I had discovered it myself 10 or 15 minutes before I read this your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There are ports of objcunit for non Mac platforms.  You can look at the [port](http://www.midnightbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/mports/devel/objcunit/) in MidnightBSD that works with GNUstep.  The patches should work for other environments too. The pkg-descr has the packages website and the Makefile will have the download URL.

Comment: see also on Github: 

https://github.com/tancred/ObjcUnitPrototype:

_"I'm experimenting with a new version of ObjcUnit, a unit test framwork for Objective-C that I wrote back in 2001/2002 together with my friend and co-worker Peter Lindberg. ObjcUnit was an adaption (almost a direct translation) of jUnit to Objective-C..."_

Answer (score 0):

For compiling objective-C, I know a quick and dirty (and somewhat limited) way of doing it - I do it online at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_objective-c_online.php .  That said, this compiler throws back a lot of c-99 errors which I think is due to it being a strict superset of C and not including some of the more unique features of the language (e.g.: @synthesize, or even dot notation), but it gets the job done.  I type up the code with Notepad++.  Like I said, limited, but surgical.
*Also - it supports command line style input, which is solid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to me that you addressed the question different, than I had asked here: my goal is to find unit testing tool!, not the possibility to test Objective-C code by hands! Anyway thanks for a link, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) from facebook which is a replacement for Apple's `xcodebuild`. We build our Objective-C library using maven and use it only for tests instead of `xcodebuild` and it works great. The output is much more readable as compared to `xcodebuild`.

From the `xctool` page,

```
xctool is a replacement for Apple's xcodebuild that makes it easier to build 
and test iOS and Mac products.
```

One thing to note though is it does not support building targets. You can use a scheme though.